# Animimport and Animexport in blender

Tags: animation, export, import

I am new to blender and was wondering is there any way of importing and exporting animations as we do in maya (.anim)

Comment: This depends on the context. Could you please state your actual goal, this sounds like an XY Problem. I don't think Blender would profit from this, because you can easily append actions from other files.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, i have a file on which i did some animation eg a walk, now in another file i am working on another animation, now i want to add that walk here and then merge the two, so how to export this walk animation from one file and import it into another.

Comment: Precisely as I expected. Open the other file. Go to File>Append and then browse to the file containing the walk cycle. In the "Append" dialog, you can open the file and navigate to "walk.blend>Actions>walk". Double click on the desired action to "import" it to your current blend file.

Comment: Ok great, thank you!! now i know how to import, just one questing how do i export the walk, sorry i am very new to blender. Thank you!

Comment: If you just can append it from another file, there is no reason to export the animation right?